# cakephp 3 sort by deeply associated table

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp

We are not able to sort our data by deeply associated data

Even though the tables are defined with belongsTo and hasOne associations type CakePHP use subqueries on the deep levels to get the data and the fields we need to order are not present in the main query

Example:

Users.Articles.Posts

If i try to order by Articles.id it works fine because Articles is present as an INNER JOIN in the query

But by ordering with Users.Articles.Posts.id it doesn't work because the Posts are being retrieved using a separate query

Is there any other way to force CakePHP to retrieve all the data in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Re-think how are you querying your tables....

When you do `Users.Articles.Posts` you are basically saying I am interested in the Users primarily and some additional associated data. So you can easily sort the `Users` because you will get a collections of Users.

But you want to sort by Posts.id then maybe you need to rethink your query and what is important to you. And instead do query the Posts table like `Posts.Articles.Users` (assuming you have the correct associations linking back as well). If you do this, you may need to use [`matching`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data) if you need to apply filters to your users and articles as well.

#### Collections of Entities

So, decide what is your priority and reformulate your query accordingly and CakePHP will help. But think in terms of collections of objects instead of thinking in terms of "how do I get Cake to generate this SQL that I have my head". It will be easier to use Cake's ORM that way.

Good luck!